# Checking if ArrayList contains anything but one element

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the most elegant way to check if an arraylist contains one (and just one) value?

For example, how can I check if my `arraylist` contains just zeroes:

```
        [0,0,0,0]; [0,0,0,0,0]; [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; <-- All should return true.
```

I know there are lots of ways to do this, including a very basic `for-loop` but is there an elegant, possibly one-line solution that uses the standard API?

Comment: @crazydevloper What do you mean!?

Comment: i also mean that use `public boolean isAllSame(ArrayList<?> list)` but unfortunately someone answered you..checkout answer of standika.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the elements to a set, and check the size with something like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (new java.util.HashSet<Integer>(
      Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }))
      .size() == 1
      && new java.util.HashSet<Integer>(
          Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0 })).size() == 1
      && new java.util.HashSet<Integer>(
          Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 0, 0, 0, 0,
              0, 0, 0, 0 })).size() == 1) {
    System.out.println("All true");
  } else {
    System.out.println("Not true");
  }
}
```

Which will output `All true`, unless you add a non zero value to any of the `Integer[]`s.

Or, as a generic method

```
public static <T> boolean oneValue(java.util.List<T> in) {
   // A one-liner.
   return (in == null) ? false : new java.util.HashSet<T>(in).size() == 1;
}
```

It is true that these are less efficient then simply looping through the `List`, like this -

```
public static <T> boolean oneValue(java.util.List<T> in) {
  if (in == null)
    return false;
  T o = in.get(0);
  for (int i = 1; i < in.size(); i++)
    if (!in.get(i).equals(o))
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Just as @Sibbo mentioned for loop is more efficient here. If you really just want to check  that there is just one unique value go with for loop. If you also want to know all unique values this solution is fine.

Comment: I guess it depends on your interpretation of "elegant."  I don't consider "more efficient" the same as "more elegant." `set.size() == 1` is far more elegant in my view, because it is clean, easy to read, and easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following:

```
public boolean isAllSame(ArrayList<?> list){
    Object first=list.get(0);
    for(int i=1;i<list.size();i++){
        if(!list.get(i).equals(first))return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

(Yes, it's a for loop. But, as was previously stated, it's not all that inelegant - runs in O(n) worst case and O(1) best. And only 4 lines.)

Comment: can't you remove the second line and replace (first) in condition statement by (list.get(0))?

Comment: Yes, but it's less efficient that way. This way, you only have to call `get()` once.

Comment: If you want to talk efficiency, use an iterator, preserve the previous element as you iterate and compare against it. As is your get() inside the loop is O(n) on some Lists (e.g. LinkedList) ;)

Comment: He specified that he is using an ArrayList, and so get() is O(1). But yes, that could be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Put all array elements in a single arraylist and then put it in hashset and check size. If size is 1 then it will return/print true.

```
    Set<Integer> val= new HashSet<Integer>();
    List<Integer> allVal= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    allVal.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 }));
    allVal.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 0, 0, 0, 0,0 }));
    allVal.addAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0 }));

    val.addAll(allVal);
    if(val.size()==1)
        System.out.println("All true");
    else
        System.out.println("More than 1 element present");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
    List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 });

    int temp = Integer.parseInt(lst.toString().replaceAll(", ", "").replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("]", "").trim());
    if(temp == 0) {
        System.out.println("All zeros");
    }
```